# Polars: how to create a dataframe from arrow RecordBatch?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow, rust-polars

I am using [rust arrow library](https://docs.rs/arrow/latest/arrow/) and have a RecordBatch struct. I want to create a Polars dataframe out it, do some operations in the Polars land, and move the result back to RecordBatch. Since both are arrow based, I suppose there might be an efficient way to convert back and forth.

What is the best way to convert RecordBatch to Polars Dataframe and vice versa in Rust?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this at the end??